# Cant deploy django-tailwind development server

Tags: css, node.js, django, tailwind-css, django-tailwind

Ive followed django-tailwind installation docs and did everything until last step, however, when I try to run 'python manage.py tailwind start', I got the following error:

```
`(venv) catatal@catatal-Predator-PH315-52:~/dev/portal_prosesmt$ python manage.py tailwind start

> theme@3.8.0 start
> npm run dev


> theme@3.8.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development tailwindcss --postcss -i ./src/styles.css -o ../static/css/dist/styles.css -w

/home/catatal/dev/portal_prosesmt/theme/static_src/node_modules/postcss-load-config/node_modules/lilconfig/src/index.js:161
        } = getOptions(name, options ?? {}, false);
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/catatal/dev/portal_prosesmt/theme/static_src/node_modules/postcss-load-config/src/index.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)`
```

My node version is: 12.22.9;
My npm version is: 8.5.1;
Ubuntu is 20.0.4.

Ive changed postcss.config.js file from:

```
`module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "postcss-simple-vars": {},
    "postcss-nested": {}
  },
}`
```

to:

```
`export const plugins = {
  "postcss-import": {},
  "postcss-simple-vars": {},
  "postcss-nested": {}
};`
```

As suggested from VS Code, however it didnt solve the problem.